# How to change the Input Timing?

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I'm trying to follow along with [this](https://eewiki.net/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=15925278) wiki page (particularly the quartus project file under 'Supporting Example Material') to figure out how to use the vga controller provided. My main objective is to get the yellow block to appear on my monitor as shown in the code in this quartus project. However after I import the project into quartus, compile it, and then place it on the board my monitor says, "The current input timing is not supported by the monitor display. Please change your input timing to 1920 x 1080 60 Hz or any other monitor listed timing as per the monitor specifications." Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What resolutions does your monitor support? What resolution are you sending it?

Comment: My monitor wants 1920 x 1080 at 60 Hz and I think I'm sending it 1920 x 1200 at 50 Hz. I think I can change the resolution in the vga_controller.vhd file but I'm not sure how to change the refresh rate from 50 to 60 Hz. From what I can tell that is defined within the PLL (which is in a schematic file) and I have not learned about PLLs yet. Whenever I change the value in the schematic design it throws this a non specific error and forces me to abort the change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The refresh rate must be changed alongside with the synchronisation periods (HSYNC, VSYNC) of the video signal. The timings are standardized by [VESA](http://www.vesa.org/). A good start is to search for *VESA Coordinated Video Timing* (CVT), then you will find a spreadsheet to calculate the required timing. The spreadsheet is part of the [VESA Free Standards](http://www.vesa.org/vesa-standards/free-standards/).

The example design of the wiki uses a resolution of 1920x1200 @ 60 Hz (!) without reduced blanking which requires a pixel clock frequency of 193.25 MHz. According to the documentation, a PLL inside the FPGA is used which generates a 193.16 MHz clock out of the 50 MHz board clock. Thus, the refresh rate would be actually: 60 Hz * 193.16 MHz / 193.25 MHz = 59.97 Hz. This is within the allowed range (59 to 61 Hz) of most TFT monitors.

To change the resolution to 1920x1080@60Hz the required pixel clock frequency decreases to 173.0 MHz without reduced blanking or even further to 138.5 MHz with reduced blanking (only for TFTs). In the provided example code, the *Mega Wizard Plugin-In Manager* has been used to generate an appropiate PLL configuration. Open the wizard from the *Tools* menu of Quartus-II, then select the already existing configuration `altpll0.vhd` and edit the settings accordingly. (The vga_pll.vhd is for an older FPGA type.)

Please note, that you **must also** change the HSYNC and VSYNC timing which is configured by the generics of the `vga_controller` module. The required numbers will be found in the CVT spreadsheet or any other modeline calculator.

Comment: Thanks man I really appreciate it. Another thing to note for other people is that the pll becomes disconnected from the vga controller in the schematic design when you change the refresh rate so you just need to reconnect the wires in the schematic file.